# Two Way sync between specific Photos App albums and Google Drive?

Tags: iphone, photos, data-synchronization

Can a two-way sync be created between the Photos App (from iPhone/Mac) and Google Drive?

I need to sync specific albums on the Photo App to Google Drive such that when a photo is added to the album (from iPhone/Mac) it appears on Google Drive. When I add a photo to the album from Google Drive it appears in the photo album on my iPhone/Mac.

How can this be done?