# How to Obtain specific albums from Photos Library in finder?

Tags: finder, photos

I need to access specific photo albums in the Finder folder system.

The albums in Photos app look like this:

[image]

The corresponding Photos Library in finder looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way to find these albums within finder?

Comment: I don't think it stores them in the same way - as you can have the same photo in multiple albums, but you wouldn't want the data multiple times in Finder.

Comment: The internal file structure of the Photos library is very opaque, and not really designed for user navigation. Can you explain why your need to access the phones through the Finder, and not from within Photos.app, exporting if necessary? Or using the "Share" or "Edit With.." menu items?

Comment: @benwiggy, I need to sync this particular album with a google drive folder. Since this is a work-related folder, I would like to keep it in sync with a shared Google Drive folder. Does this make sense?

Comment: So this leads on from https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/465144/two-way-sync-between-specific-photos-app-albums-and-google-drive which does really make it a bit of an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: @Tetsujin, both can be seen as separate questions requiring separate solutions. The other question you refer to can possibly be solved via third-party apps such as Photosync. The question above is different and potentially interesting to other users.

Comment: Yeah, but the answer to this one is 'you can't think of it that way, that's not how it works'

Comment: Photos isn't designed for this kind of usage. You'll need to export your photos, and just use Google Drive for this work.